# Look for Column and then filter

Tags: excel, vba

I have headers starting on A3 and I am trying to get this code to look for column "Team Manager" and then filter on a login name.

Here is my code but it is not working sadly.

```
Sub FilterNames()

    Dim col As String, cfind As Range

    col = "Team Manager"
    With ActiveSheet.Select
        With .Range("A3", .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
            Set cfind = .Find(what:=col, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not cfind Is Nothing Then
                .AutoFilter Field:=cfind.Column, Criteria1:="login123" '                   
            End If
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an interesting little problem.  Please try the following code, based on all your headers being in row 3, on the sheet called `Sheet1` - change these to suit.

```
Option Explicit
Sub FilterNames()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long, col As Long

Const login = "login123"
Const header = "T*M*"

Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
col = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(header, ws.Range("3:3"), 0)
LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, col).End(xlUp).Row

With ws.Range(ws.Cells(3, col), ws.Cells(LastRow, col))
    .AutoFilter 1, login
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: One last question, hope you can help. Is there a way to look for either "Team Manager" or "TM"? some sheets will have Team Manager and the others might have TM.

Comment: Awesome, thank you @kevin9999 I will appreciate it.

Comment: Done!  Just change `"Team Manager"` to `"T*M*"` - see the amended code.  Tested & works for me.

Comment: It works PERFECT, thank you so much for all this help. Really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is in this line:

```
With .Range("A3", .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
```

you are looking for last column in your Filtered headers, which is in your 3rd row, so it needs to be:

```
With .Range("A3", .Cells(3, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
```

Also, try to avoid using `ActiveSheet` and `Select`.

***Modified Code***

```
Option Explicit

Sub FilterNames()

    Dim col As String, cfind As Range
    Dim Sht As Worksheet
    
    Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")  ' <-- modify "Sheet1" to your sheet's name
    col = "Team Manager"
    With Sht
        With .Range("A3", .Cells(3, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft))
            Set cfind = .Find(what:=col, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
            If Not cfind Is Nothing Then
                .AutoFilter Field:=cfind.Column, Criteria1:="login123" '
            End If
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: @Lalaland at which line ?

Comment: Set Sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

Comment: @Lalaland you need to modify `"Sheet1"` to your worksheet's name